# How to get rating back for an account at chess.com closed for fair play reasons?

Tags: online-chess, chess.com

I played a couple of chess games with my friend for money and he won. Today I noticed his account was closed for fair play reasons. When I ask him he admits that he cheated me on that game. He gave me money he won. We have been playing chess together like 5 years in chess.com, he has good ratings. He swears that he didn't cheat in other games. I believe him because I have played plenty of games with him offline; he is a pretty good player. chess.com had sent him an email that says "your account is closed and create a new account". The question is, if he creates a new account, will he be able to get his rating back? The mail say they'll give the same login details, avatar etc.

Answer (score 2):

Cheating on chess.com is viewed as an offence that in the majority of cases is unforgivable. I'd like to refer you to the [following guidelines (#4) by a former mod](https://www.chess.com/forum/view/help-support/how-to-recover-a-closed-account?page=4) on chess.com:

> That account was closed for Fair Play violations: you need to contact Chess.com Support via Help --> Ask a Question --> Contact and you can either choose to appeal your account closure or admit to cheating and ask for a second chance. If the former is successful - and that's very, very unlikely given the certainty level that Chess.com uses for account closures - then your account will be restored. In the latter case, Chess.com will let you create a new account, but you won't get your old account back. They will, however, help with renaming of accounts so your new account can have the same name as your old account.

> > If your account has been closed for Fair Play violations, any new accounts will also be closed as soon as Chess.com identifies them. You have to contact Support before they will let you back on the site

Wherefore, **If your account has been closed for Fair Play violations, any new accounts will also be closed as soon as Chess.com identifies them. You can either appeal your account closure or admit to cheating and ask for a second chance. If the former is successful, then your account will be restored.**